# How to create a form similar to Google's sign-in form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

Currently I am working on a site in which I am making a contact form inspired by Google's material design sign-in form.

The effect that I want is like when I click on the input field, the value (which is a label) should change it's position, size and color. It has been successfully implemented too but the effect is only taking place in the input fields with "required" attribute.

The same effect cannot be achieved in the default input fields.

```css
.civildaily-form {
  display: block;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input.form-control,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ced4da;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].form-control:focus,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].form-control:focus,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.civildaily-form label {
  font-family: "Raleway-Bold", Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #282828;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].form-control:valid~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].form-control:valid~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #004880;
}
```

```html
<form class="civildaily-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <label for="Company Name">Company Name</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the  [image: **Screenshot**]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to add `left: 0;` to your css for `.civildaily-form label` and remove your conflicting css selectors for `:valid` pseudo class on your `input` elements.

You can't reliably detect whether the `input` is empty with css only across all major browsers (the `:valid` pseudo-class you are using will only work for `required` fields, you could also use a hack with the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class but browser support is limited). JavaScript is the more reliable way to detect whether or not the `input` is empty to apply the appropriate label positioning styles (added a `.filled` class to the css to work with the javascript, but you could name it anything you want).

Working snippet below:

```js
const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
for (const field of fields) {
  field.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
    const sel = event.target;
    if (sel.value) {
      sel.classList.add('filled');
    } else {
      sel.classList.remove('filled');
    }  
  });
}
```

```css
.civildaily-form {
  display: block;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input.form-control,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ced4da;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].form-control:focus,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].form-control:focus,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.civildaily-form label {
  font-family: "Raleway-Bold", Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #282828;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.form-control:focus~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='text'].filled~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group input[type='email'].filled~label,
.civildaily-form .form-group textarea.filled:focus~label{
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #004880;
}
```

```html
<form class="civildaily-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="" required>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" required>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="text">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="company" type="text">
    <label for="company">Company Name</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi,

I have tried removing the pseudo class :valid previously but its creating a different problem.

Whenever the input field is filled up and clicked outside, the label text is changing its position back to the input field overlapping the text inside the input field

Comment: Good point. Updated the answer with some javascript you will need to handle label position based on whether or not the field has been filled (unfortunately css can't detect whether or not `input` is filled).